# Radio Button from another activity remains null?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-radiobutton

In one activity I have my radio buttons. I'm able to save the selected state of the radio buttons throughout the application. In another activity I want to check which radio button is checked, but the radio buttons keep returning null.

Here's the first activity:

```
sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GetInfo, MODE_PRIVATE);


go_back_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_back_btn);
distancebtn_group = findViewById(R.id.distance_btn_group);
miles_btn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.miles_btn);
kilometer_btn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.kilometer_btn);


go_back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GetInfo, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(MILESBTN, miles_btn.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean(KMBTN, kilometer_btn.isChecked());
        editor.apply();
        Intent intent = new Intent(settings.this, home.class);
        intent.putExtra(MILESBTN, miles_btn.isChecked());
        intent.putExtra(KMBTN, kilometer_btn.isChecked());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

kilometer_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GetInfo, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(KMBTN, kilometer_btn.isChecked());
        editor.apply();


    }
});
miles_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GetInfo, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(MILESBTN, miles_btn.isChecked());
        editor.apply();
    }
});


sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GetInfo, MODE_PRIVATE);
kilometer_btn.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("kilometer_btn", true));
miles_btn.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("miles_btn", false));
```

}

Here's my second activity:

```
    distance_counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance_counter);
    distancebtn_group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.distance_btn_group);
    miles_btn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.miles_btn);
    kilometer_btn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.kilometer_btn);
    distancebtn_group = findViewById(R.id.distance_btn_group);




    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(settings.GetInfo, MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Boolean milesbutton = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(MILESBTN, false);
    final Boolean kilometerbutton = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KMBTN, true);

    Boolean milesbtn = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(MILESBTN, false);
    Boolean kilometerbtn = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(KMBTN, true);
    getIntent().getBooleanExtra(MILESBTN, false);
    getIntent().getBooleanExtra(KMBTN, true);



            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    curr_location = location;
    if (start_location == null) {
        start_location = curr_location;
        end_location = curr_location;
    } else
        end_location = curr_location;


    ChooseMetricUnits();
    distance_counter.setText(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(distance));

    current_speed = location.getSpeed() * 2.236936;
    SpdInmph.setText(new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(current_speed));

    current_speed = location.getSpeed() * 3.6;
    SpdInkmh.setText(new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(current_speed));

}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}


private void distanceInMeters() {
    distance = distance + (start_location.distanceTo(end_location));
    start_location = end_location;

}

private void distanceInMiles() {
    distance = distance + (start_location.distanceTo(end_location) * 0.00062137);


}

private void distanceInkilometers() {
    distance = distance + (start_location.distanceTo(end_location) / 1000);
    start_location = end_location;


}




public void ChooseMetricUnits() {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(settings.GetInfo, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean milesbutton = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(MILESBTN, false);
    Boolean kilometerbutton = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KMBTN, true);
    Boolean milesbtn = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(MILESBTN, true);
    Boolean kilometerbtn = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(KMBTN, true);
    getIntent().getBooleanExtra(MILESBTN, false);
    getIntent().getBooleanExtra(KMBTN, true);
    if(miles_btn.equals(milesbutton)) {
        distanceInMiles();
```

: Run

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at mobile.run_interface.ChooseMetricUnits(run_interface.java:325)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAbD4.png)

As you can see the problem is here:

```
        if(miles_btn.equals(milesbutton)) {
```

I've used BOTH putBoolean and putExtra to see if something different would happen when I pull the values from either one. Same result. I've placed the code for retrieving values, under create AND also under my ChooseMetricsUnits void method. My buttons are still null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are `GetInfo` and `settings.GetInfo` equal in the `getSharedPreferences()` calls?

Comment: Yes. they're the same. I don't even have to add the settings to GetInfo. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem:

Hopes this helps anyone else in the future...\

```
    private void ChooseMetricUnits() {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GetInfo, MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Boolean MetricUnit = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(settings.KMBTN, true);
    if(MetricUnit) {
        distanceInkilometers();
    } else
        distanceInMiles();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Has the activities the same layout? If they are not the same checks the import of R.id.miles_btn

And here there is another problem:

```
        if(miles_btn.equals(milesbutton))
```

miles_btn is the RadioButton and milesbutton is a Boolean, so you must to change the code by:

```
    if(miles_btn.isChecked() == milesbutton)
```

Comment: The activities have different layouts. The first activity is the settings. In the settings the user has the option to choose miles or kilometer. This should affect the metric unit used in the activity interface/2nd activity. If the radio button for miles is selected, then the method used should be private void distanceInMiles() { . By default or selection, the radio button for kilometer uses private void distanceInkilometers() {

Comment: If the activites have differents layouts but the views have the same id, please check the syntethic Kotlin import, the schema must be something like: kotlinx.android.synthetic.yourPackage.your_activity_name.*